# Possible race condition With http2 implementation

Tags: http, go, mutex, race-condition

I have a curious issue, which happens in production very infrequently.

I have a gobal http client to reuse connections.

```
DefaultClient = &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   500 * time.Millisecond,
            KeepAlive: 1 * time.Minute,
        }).DialContext,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 500 * time.Millisecond,
        MaxIdleConns:        3000,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 3000,
        IdleConnTimeout:     1 * time.Minute,
    },
    Timeout: 500 * time.Millisecond,
}
```

Every so often a machine will become unresponsive because it is unable to recover from a panic, which seems to be related to mutex locking and unlocking within the Go standard http lib.

```
goroutine 47888935 [semacquire, 7 minutes]:
sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex(0xc00040126c, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:71 +0x3d
sync.(*Mutex).Lock(0xc000401268)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/mutex.go:134 +0xff
net/http.(*http2clientConnPool).getClientConn(0xc000401260, 0xc028295f00, 0xc0281de820, 0x12, 0xc00027a400, 0xc0283266a8, 0x6aafa0, 0xc00027a410)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:760 +0x65
net/http.http2noDialClientConnPool.GetClientConn(0xc000401260, 0xc028295f00, 0xc0281de820, 0x12, 0xc0281de820, 0x12, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:954 +0x4e
net/http.(*http2Transport).RoundTripOpt(0xc00027a410, 0xc028295f00, 0x0, 0x200000000000000, 0x4137ec, 0xb940aa)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:7031 +0x105
net/http.(*http2Transport).RoundTrip(0xc00027a410, 0xc028295f00, 0x1, 0xc028307800, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:6999 +0x3a
net/http.http2noDialH2RoundTripper.RoundTrip(0xc00027a410, 0xc028295f00, 0xc0282cf800, 0x5, 0xc00059c2c8)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:1019 +0x39
net/http.(*Transport).roundTrip(0xc000177680, 0xc028295f00, 0xc028267a70, 0xc02801ff88, 0xc02801ff90)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:415 +0xd4c
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0xc000177680, 0xc028295f00, 0xc000177680, 0xbf0c9388b63791ca, 0x2122772ff0fc)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/roundtrip.go:17 +0x35
net/http.send(0xc028295e00, 0xc99600, 0xc000177680, 0xbf0c9388b63791ca, 0x2122772ff0fc, 0x11d03a0, 0xc027ef3480, 0xbf0c9388b63791ca, 0xc028326cb8, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:250 +0x14b
net/http.(*Client).send(0xc000400360, 0xc028295e00, 0xbf0c9388b63791ca, 0x2122772ff0fc, 0x11d03a0, 0xc027ef3480, 0x0, 0x1, 0xc000518000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:174 +0xfa
net/http.(*Client).do(0xc000400360, 0xc028295e00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:641 +0x2a8
net/http.(*Client).Do(0xc000400360, 0xc028295e00, 0x10, 0xb933f5, 0x4)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:509 +0x35
```

It happens so infrequently in high traffic, production that it's hard to reproduce.

Has anyone experienced this before or has any insights at the possible problem?  It seems tightly coupled with the http client.

Comment: Have you run it with the race detector? Are you sure you're not running out of system resources, like memory?

Comment: @JimB yeah i've run all the tests with the race flag on, separately I split traffic to a dev box which ran the binary with race on. Though, it could be memory related. I see dips in usage memory right around the time these panics happen.. Though the usable memory isn't 0, its more like a 20% dip.

Comment: This doesn't look like a race, and that goroutine stack doesn't help so much -- though `semacquire, 7 minutes` does look like a problem, it's just not the cause. You'd have to look though the full stack trace if possible for goroutines blocked while holding that mutex. (SO isn't really the place for troubleshooting these things, I would take this over to the mailing list.)

Comment: @JimB, looking deeper I do believe it is memory related, this ticket safe to close. But given points have been distributed why don't you answer so that i can accept it. Thank you